# Angular - toggling a class in combination with ngIf does not seem to work

Tags: angular

I am creating a component based on a condition:

```html
<div *ngIf="showContainer" class="container">
```

And now I want to add some animation to it, meaning I want to blend in the container instead of having it just pop up. I was thinking about the following:

```html
<div *ngIf="showContainer" class="container" [ngClass]="{'show': showContainer, 'hide': !showContainer}">
```

And then in my SCSS file, I am adding the following:

```css
.container {
   transition: opacity 3s linear;
      
   &.show {
     opacity: 1;
   }
    
   &.hide {
     opacity: 0;
   }
}
```

Now, this animation does not work at all. I am toggling the `showContainer` variable on clicking an icon and I have verified that the variable is actually being toggled! I have a feeling this might be connected to the `*ngIf` directive. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Maybe remove the `ngIf` and see how that goes.

Comment: If showComtainer is false, by the *ngIf there is no div to have class 'hide'

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64707211/transition-not-working-correctly-when-element-is-added-to-the-dom.

Comment: works like a charm without the `ngIf`. However, I would rather have the `ngIf`, since I might have multiple components, i.e. multiple containers on one page. The `ngIf` ensures that a container is only rendered when clicking on a toggle-button for a specific container. I wouldn't like to clutter my page with multiple hidden containers. Is it possible to animate the creation of a component? I checked out the following question, but this doesn't seem to work either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417931/angular-2-ngif-and-css-transition-animation

Answer (score 0):

please, try to use the class as follow.

### Proper way

```html
<div *ngIf="showContainer" class="container"
  [class.show]="showContainer"
  [class.hide]="!showContainer"
>
```

*Cannot tell you the reason why this isn't working, seems to be good to me. But what I could experience is that, if you're already using a `class` the `[ngClass]` wont be taking in account, since it's the same attribute.*

#### Other way: ngClass

Remove the `class="container"` an put it into the `ngClass` with a default `true` value.

```html
<div *ngIf="showContainer" [ngClass]="{'container': true, 'show': showContainer, 'hide': !showContainer}">
```